# Array_merge wont merge

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, merge

There's this website a friend asked me to make some changes to. It uses Laravel framework.

I've made some database calls to get some data but when i try to merge the data in another array nothing comes out. What seems to be the problem here?

```
public function show_opfolgningsoversigt() {
    $complete = array();

    $surveys = DB::table('surveys')->where('company_id', \Auth::user()->company_id)->get();
    foreach($surveys as $survey) {
        $questions = DB::table('questions')->where('survey_id', $survey->id)->get();
        foreach($questions as $question) {
            $answers = DB::table('answers')->where('question_id', $question->id)->get();
            foreach($answers as $answer) {
                array_merge($complete, array("recipient" => $answers->recipient_id, "followup" => $answers->followup);
            }
        }
    }
    $followups = $complete;

    return view('survey.opfolgningsoversigt')->with('followups', $followups);
}
```

All variables except $complete outputs what it should. Which means $answers->recipient_id and $answers->followup returns int.

Comment: *"What seems to be the problem here?"* -- the problem is that you expect us to guess what is the input, the expected output and the actual output of the code. Make sure the code fetches some data from the database before assuming `array_merge()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

array_merge returns an array, in your code your not using the returned result.

```
$complete = array_merge($complete, array("recipient" => $answers->recipient_id, "followup" => $answers->followup);
```

Is probably what your trying to achieve.